# How to check a c++11 tuple in runtime for possible function application

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple

I have a function applying a given function `f` to a given `std::tuple`  `t` as below, in which if the `t` is of wrong size, a compile time error message is generated. I was wondering if it is possible to write it differently so that when the tuple size is wrong, the function-call does not happen (maybe using `enable_if` or something like that) and a runtime error message is generated ( instead of the compile time error message).

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<int ...> struct seq {};

template<int N, int ...S> struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...> {};

template<int ...S> struct gens<0, S...>{ typedef seq<S...> type; };

template <typename R, typename Tp, typename ...FArgs> 
struct t_app_aux {
  template<int ...S>
  R static callFunc(std::function<R (FArgs...)> f,Tp t,seq<S...>) {
    return f(std::get<S>(t) ...);
  }
};

template <typename R, typename Tp, typename ...FArgs>
R t_app(std::function<R (FArgs...)> f, Tp t) {
  static_assert(std::tuple_size<Tp>::value == sizeof...(FArgs), "type error: t_app wrong arity"); //wrong size generates a compile error, how about runtime check?
  return t_app_aux<R, Tp, FArgs...>::callFunc(f,t,typename gens<sizeof...(FArgs)>::type());
}

int main(void)
{
  std::tuple<int, float, double> t = std::make_tuple(1, 1.2, 5);
  std::function<double (int,float,double)> foo = [](int x, float y, double z) {
    return x + y + z;
  };
  std::cout <<  t_app(foo,t) << std::endl;
}
```

-- Update --

A little bit of motivation and explanation of what I have in mind. It may be politically incorrect, but say, I want to compare an input tuple to a fixed tuple defined inside a template function `compare_me` (say the inside tuple is `make_tuple(2,3)` ). If I could suppress the compile-time error, then I can return a `false` on `compare_me(make_tuple(1,2,3))` or `compare_me(make_tuple(1,2))` and `true` on `make_tuple(2,3)` only. More practically, the same technique can be used to write a template `eq` to compare two tuples of potentially different sizes and return `false` when their sizes does not match.

The size mismatch can be treated as a compile error. And I do agree that a true failure should be exposed early. But I guess there are times when one may want to be lenient or reconsider what is a true failure. This is true especially considering there are functions like `std::tuple_cat` that can actually give your function a tuple of varying sizes.

Comment: Why do you want to exchange a compile time fail for a runtime fail? Fail early is kind of a C++ motto. If you better describe the problem you are looking to solve, there may be a better answer.

Comment: How do you make a runtime-sized tuple?

Comment: I think it's not necessary to generate runtime-sized tuples for this case. `template<typename Tp> int f(Tp t) { return tuple_size<Tp>::value;}` can already handle tuples of different sizes. What I am asking is if,e.g, two tuples of different sizes can be compared without generating a compile error.

Comment: You may also do   `if (true) f(make_tuple()); else f(make_tuple(1,2));`. I think as long as no return type or variable re-use is involved, tuples of different sizes can still be used together.

Answer (score 2):

Use `enable_if` and the condition in your `static_assert` to conditionally enable the current function only when the sizes match. Create another function that is enabled only when the condition is false, and throw an exception from this function.

```
template <typename R, typename Tp, typename ...FArgs>
auto t_app(std::function<R (FArgs...)> f, Tp t)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::tuple_size<Tp>::value == sizeof...(FArgs), R>::type {
//  static_assert(std::tuple_size<Tp>::value == sizeof...(FArgs), "type error: t_app wrong arity"); //wrong size generates a compile error, how about runtime check?
  return t_app_aux<R, Tp, FArgs...>::callFunc(f,t,typename gens<sizeof...(FArgs)>::type());
}

template <typename R, typename Tp, typename ...FArgs>
auto t_app(std::function<R (FArgs...)>, Tp)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::tuple_size<Tp>::value != sizeof...(FArgs), R>::type {
  throw std::runtime_error("type error: t_app wrong arity");
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd05d1d27368437f)

Comment: I must say it's a bit odd you want to trade a compile-time error for a runtime error.

Comment: The goal in C++ is not to get your program to complie: it is to get your program to fail to compile if it is incorrect as much as reasonable while not impeding correct programs from compiling, nor slowing them down.  There are reasons to use the above technique, but they are quite rare.

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks a lot for your answer. Is it also possible for the two functions to return the same type `R`? For example, can I have the function return `true` if their sizes match and `false` if not? That's what I intended to have in the std::function signature.